# Can't get Firestore to convert snapshot documents into 'Photo' objects

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having trouble migrating `getPhotos` method using Firebase Realtime Database to `getPhotos1` using Firestore, but for some reason can't get the document snapshot in `getPhotos1` to the `Photos1` object.

This is my `getPhotos` method using Firebase Realtime Database:

```
static func getPhotos (completion: @escaping ([Photo]) -> Void) {

    //Getting a reference to the database
    let dbRef = Database.database().reference()

    //Make the db call
    dbRef.child("photos").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        //Declare an array to hold the photos
        var retrievedPhotos = [Photo]()

        //Get the list of snapshots
        let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]

        if let snapshots = snapshots {

            //Loop through each snapshot and parse out the photos
            for snap in snapshots {

                //Try to create a photo from a snapshot
                let p = Photo(snapshot: snap)

                //If successful, then add it to our array
                if p != nil {
                    retrievedPhotos.insert(p!, at: 0)

                }
            }
        }
        //After parsing the snapshots, call the completion closure
        completion(retrievedPhotos)
    }
}
```

This is it's object

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase

class Photo: Object {

    @objc dynamic var photoId:String?
    @objc dynamic var byId:String?
    @objc dynamic var byUsername:String?
    @objc dynamic var date:String?
    @objc dynamic var url:String?
    @objc dynamic var postId:String?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "photoId"
    }

    override static func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["byUsername"]
    }

    convenience init?(snapshot:DataSnapshot){
        self.init ()

        //Photo data
        let photoData = snapshot.value as? [String:String]

        if let photoData = photoData {

            let photoId = snapshot.key
            let byId = photoData["byId"]
            let byUsername = photoData["byUsername"]
            let date = photoData["date"]
            let url = photoData["url"]
            let postId = photoData["postId"]

            guard byId != nil && byUsername != nil && date != nil && url != nil && postId != nil else {
                return nil
            }
            self.photoId = photoId
            self.byId = byId
            self.byUsername = byUsername
            self.date = date
            self.url = url
            self.postId = postId

        }
    }
}
```

This is my `getPhotos1` method using Firestore, **which is not working**:

```
    static func getPhotos1 (completion: @escaping ([Photo1]) -> Void) {

    //Get a Firebase reference
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("posts").getDocuments() {snapshot, error  in

        //Declare an array to hold the photos
        var retrievedPhotos = [Photo1]()

        if error == nil && snapshot != nil {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let p = Photo1(snapshot: document)
                print(p!)
                if p != nil {
                retrievedPhotos.insert(p!, at: 0)
                //print("retrievedPhotos: \(retrievedPhotos)")
                }
            }
        }
        //After parsing the snapshots, call the completion closure
        completion(retrievedPhotos)
    }
}
```

And this is it's object

```
class Photo1: Object {

@objc dynamic var photoId:String?
@objc dynamic var byId:String?
@objc dynamic var byUsername:String?
@objc dynamic var date:String?
@objc dynamic var url:String?
@objc dynamic var postId:String?

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "photoId"
}

override static func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["byUsername"]
}

convenience init?(snapshot:DocumentSnapshot){
    self.init ()

    //Photo data
    let photoData = snapshot.data() as? [String:String]

    if let photoData = photoData {

        let photoId = snapshot.documentID
        let byId = photoData["byId"]
        let byUsername = photoData["byUsername"]
        let date = photoData["date"]
        let url = photoData["url"]
        let postId = photoData["postId"]

        guard byId != nil && byUsername != nil && date != nil && url != nil && postId != nil else {
            return nil
        }
        self.photoId = photoId
        self.byId = byId
        self.byUsername = byUsername
        self.date = date
        self.url = url
        self.postId = postId

    }
}
}
```

EDITED 10/1:
Updated getPhoto1 method.

```
static func getPhotos1 (completion: @escaping ([Photo1]) -> Void) {

    //Get a Firebase reference
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("posts").getDocuments() { (snapshot, error)  in

        //Declare an array to hold the photos
        var retrievedPhotos = [Photo1]()
        print("This is snapshot: \(String(describing: snapshot))")

        if error == nil && snapshot != nil {

            for document in snapshot!.documents {

                let documentData = document.data()

                print("This is DocData: \(documentData)")

                let p = Photo1(snapshot: documentData)
                print("This is p: \(p)")
                if p != nil {
                retrievedPhotos.insert(p!, at: 0)
                print("retrievedPhotos: \(retrievedPhotos)")
                }}}
        //After parsing the snapshots, call the completion closure
        completion(retrievedPhotos)
    }}
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type 'DocumentSnapshot'
```

Thanks for the advice in advance.

I tried to search for a previous thread on this and while there are a few, I couldn't figure it out as they weren't Swift specific.

Comment: The question seems incomplete. Nothing in your Firestore code matches your Firebase Realtime Database code. You're reading two different node names (photos and posts), your Photo object uses RTDB code (e.g. there isn't a an object using Firestore code) and most importantly, your Firestore code doesn't really do anything except read the documents in your Posts collection. Can you fix the question and clarify what you're asking?

Comment: After removing some of the commenting // in the 'getPhotos1' method I'm trying to do the same thing of converting the snapshot documents in p which is the same as converting the snap into p in 'getPhotos'.  In the Photo's object I know when i begin using 'getPhotos1' method I'll have to change a few things to make it work such as 'DataSnapshot' to 'DocumentSnapshot' etc.  

I specifically need help in getting the 'getPhotos1' method to return the full array of Photo's in retrievedPhotos like it does in 'getPhotos'.  Right now it returns nil or  won't even build depending on what i try

Comment: I think you missed my meaning. Your code `let p = Photo(snapshot: document)` is passing a Firestore **DocumentSnapshot** to your Photo object which requires a Firebase Real Time Database **DataSnapshot** object and the two are NOT compatible. Therefore the Photo object is not created and cannot be added to an array. You need to update your Photo object to be initialized with a Firestore **DocumentSnapshot** object.

Comment: I updated the Photo object (now Photo1) for getPhoto1 to ensure it's using the correct Firestore protocols but p (in getPhoto1 method) still is returning nil for object

Comment: next thing is to add error checking. If there are any errors your code just keeps going without notifying you.

Comment: Any suggestions on what to add?  I’m new to coding in general so any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems you are using Realm along with Firebase (as indicated by Object and primaryKey) which is fine but those are not used with Firebase. If I remove those references and run your code, it works, so it's unclear what the issue is. It may be due to Firestore Rules, mismatched structure or perhaps your fields don't exist so it's returning nil. YOU need to do some basic troubleshooting - you can start with adding a breakpoint to your code and stepping through it line by line and inspect your variables. When something isn't what you expected, that's going to be where the issue is.

Comment: Luckily the code builds fine, with our without the Realm code in the Photo1 object class, the problem is none of the document fields are getting assigned to 'p', from the snapshot.document, so the corresponding fields in p remain nil.  That's where the problem is, just not sure what part is wrong so snapshot.document can correctly assign the fields to p

Comment: Look here -> `guard byId != nil && byUsername != nil...` if any of those fields are nil, nothing will be assigned to p. PLEASE step through the code line by line starting with `let photoId = snapshot.documentID` and see which one is nil.

Comment: Ok after stepping through it gets to Photo1 ` if let photoData = photoData { ` and skips everything within that statement which is why the object p is returning nil. Now to figure out why nothing is being assigned to p from the snapshot

Comment: Inside the convenience init, add a `print(snapshot` and see if it prints anything. If not, back up to where the object is created and add a print. So right after `for document in snapshot!.documents` add a `print(document)` and see what prints. Rinse, repeat until you find out which line is causing the issue.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for sticking with me on this @Jay, secondly when I print out snapshot from getPhoto1 i get this 
"This is snapshot: Optional(<FIRQuerySnapshot: 0x7fb9b8cb3ac0>)!" 
where as when i print snapshot from getPhoto I get the correct document details.  Isn't the snapshot result above just a location of the document rather than the actual document itself?

Comment: Remember earlier I said you are mixing two API's; Firebase Real Time Database and Firestore? Well, that's what's happening. RTDB uses DataSnapshot (aka FIRQuerySnapshot) whereas Firestore uses DocumentSnapshot. See here `convenience init?(snapshot:DataSnapshot)` is expecting a RTDB DataSnapshot, not a Firestore Document snapshot. Go with one or the other. And... the DataSnapshot or DocumentSnapshot contains ALL of the data in that node and is not just a reference - it's the actual data.

Comment: getPhoto1 is using the Photo1 class so I believe the APIs are correct for the corresponding DB, in this case Firestore.  I modified the  method a bit and can get documentData to print the document details now just getting the error "Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type 'DocumentSnapshot'" when trying to convert it into the Photo1 object.  See edited section above for complete method details

Comment: There are a lot of issues with the code in the question, even with revisions - it's heading the right direction but it really needs to be cleaned up. I posted a straightforward answer to try to get you on track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with the code in the question; three different API's (Firebase RealTime Database, Firestore and Realm) which I think may be causing some of the confusion.

Let's cut to the chase with a straight Firestore answer. This code will read documents within a Firestore collection, create PhotoClass objects based on that data and store them in an array. Assume the structure is this

```
photos //a collection
   photo_0 //a document
      byUserName: "Henry"
      byId: "uid_0"
   photo_1
      byUserName: "George"
      byId: "uid_1"
```

Here's a PhotoClass - I am defaulting the properties to empty strings instead of nils to reduce the need to handle nils. Since we are not using Realm, I also removed the Object definition and changed the vars to Swift vars instead of ObjC vars required by Realm (@objc dynamic)

```
class PhotoClass {
    var photoId = ""
    var byId = ""
    var byUsername = ""
    //var date:String?
    //var url:String?
    //var postId:String?

    init(withDocumentSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot) {
        self.photoId = withDocumentSnapshot.documentID
        self.byUsername = withDocumentSnapshot.get("userName") as? String ?? "No User Name"
        self.byId = withDocumentSnapshot.get("byId") as? String ?? "No uid"
    }
}
```

Note that I am defaulting values to a known string in case the read properties are nil. That way the app won't crash if a property is missing or nil. If you want to work with nil values, that's cool, but you have to protect your code by safely working with them throughout.

Then an array to store the photo's in

```
var photosArray = [PhotoClass]()
```

Then the code to read on all of the documents within the photos node, create the PhotoClass objects and populate an array

```
func readAllPhotos() {
    let photosCollection = self.db.collection("photos")
    photosCollection.getDocuments(completion: { snapshot, err in
        if let err = err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        for doc in snapshot!.documents {
            let photo = PhotoClass(withDocumentSnapshot: doc)
            self.photosArray.append(photo)
        }
    })
}
```

Again, noting there is code in place to check for errors and protect the app in case the node is not found or some other error occurs.

Comment: Thanks @Jay!!.  This worked for Firebase exclusively which is good enough for now.  I'll figure out the Realm piece later; maybe :-)

Comment: answer accepted!  Now officially off FBRT and may or may not incorporate back in Realm so for now down to 1 db